# In a single Organization of Hyperledger I want to create a multiple channels with the Fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I am new to Blockchain Technology and I'm trying to create **multiple Channels** in a **single organisation** using Hyperledger Fabric, my doubt is whether we can achieve it? If yes than how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Hyperledger support running multi-channels in one peer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838201/does-hyperledger-support-running-multi-channels-in-one-peer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838201/does-hyperledger-support-running-multi-channels-in-one-peer), you can create multiple channels with single org and whatever number of peers